# installation of PHP on windows 7

Tags: php

i have installed  PHP    on win 7  from this site

```
http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-PHP-windows-7.php
```

and when i run  this

```
 http://localhost/phpinfo.php  it gave me following error
```

Oops! This link appears to be broken.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you're trying to roll your own installation of PHP on Win7?  I can understand wanting to build a customized installation from scratch on a production server, but I presume that this is for a development/test environment. For that purpose , I would recommend uninstalling the individual components that you have been trying to integrate and installing a pre-built stack instead.

Here are links to two different pre-built stacks for Windows that include Apache, PHP, and MySQL.  Just uninstall whatever you have already tried installing, choose one of the links below, and then download and run the installer:

1. [XAMPP for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)
2. [BitNami WampStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/wampstack)

In moments, you will have a working PHP development/test environment without the fuss of manually integrating the components.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do http://127.0.0.1/phpinfo.php ?

Comment: it works  in installation guide was  written that you dont need actualy restart computer just  stop and start  appache  and just this was problem   for working it was necessary restart machine thanks everybody